# Snort Inline with 1 NIC

Tags: nic, snort

Is this possible?  A group of us have been trying to prepare for a security competition coming up, but we know we will only have 1 NIC.  We have tried for hours to research a solution, but we haven't found anything that works.  Can anyone point us in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's possible.

The best way to test playing with Snort is to download the free Linux distro, Security Onion (http://code.google.com/p/security-onion/wiki/Installation). It comes with an easy set-up wizard and has all the tools for Intrusion Detection and Network Security Monitoring.

You can use it to set the server and sensor elements for Snort on the one nic in the VM, eth0 typically. You'll be up and running within 10 minutes of booting the VM.